# C# TcpListener and WCF service on same port

Tags: c#, wcf, tcplistener, nettcpbinding

is it possible to share the same port for a TcpListener and a nettcpbinding WCF service?

WCF address : "net.tcp://localhost:8888/Test/Services/TestService"
TcpListener: Ip: Any, Port : 8888

Comment: How would Windows know to which application send the data to? No, two applications can never listen on the same port at the same time, and it is not even related to .NET.

Comment: Absolutely not.  Two processes can never share the same port.

Comment: Yes I thought so, but I was wondering if .Net can do something like this. I mean you can also create different services on the same port...

Comment: In that case you still have exactly one process, not two

Comment: @Franki1986 absolutely not.  the OS does not allow two processes to share the same port.

Comment: Ok thanks! The way a nettcp service is working in core is not 100% clear to me I am getting more and more in to it , but there will remain always a question mark...

Comment: No, but you can share the same port between 2 different net.tcp endpoints using the [net.tcp port sharing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/net-tcp-port-sharing)